# dispose() is called when using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-state

I am under the impression that using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` would prevent the states `dispose()` callback from being called when the Widget isn't visible anymore.

However, I have a situation where `dispose()` and `initState()` get called every time I hide/show a Widget, even though I implemented `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` correctly.

```
class IdleScreenState extends State<IdleScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('IdleScreen initState');
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    print('IdleScreen dispose');
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    // ...build the page...
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

}
```

This is how I hide/show this Widget

```
class MainScreen extends State<MainScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return somecondition ? IdleScreen() : OtherScreen();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

}
```

Every time this Widget (screen) is shown, `initState()`gets called, and every time I hide it, `dispose()` gets called. It's as if the `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` has no effect. All other similar issues I could find seem to be due to either missing the `wantKeepAlive => true` or the `super.build(context)`, but they are 100% there in the code.

I tried supplying a `GlobalKey` for `IdleScreen` as well, but that didn't have any effect.

However, if I use an `IndexedStack` or `Offstage` to hide/show the widget, it works as expected (`initState()` and `dispose()` don't get called when hiding/showing the widget).

```
  IndexedStack(
    index: somecondition ? 0 : 1,
    children: [
      IdleScreen(),
      OtherScreen()
    ],
  ),
```

Maybe I'm mistaken, but isn't the whole purpose of `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to not have to manually keep the widget around using this technique?

This is in a web project, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

*The type argument T is the type of the StatefulWidget subclass of the State into which this class is being mixed.*

you have to pass the widget class name like this..

```
class IdleScreenState extends State<IdleScreen> 
     with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin <IdleScreen> {...
```